# System couldn't find an existing file after publish

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5

I am running the following c# code in .Net5.0:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\dsregcmd.exe"));
    Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\").ToList().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
}
```

When running it from Visual Studio or from `cmd` using the `dotnet` command the first reports `true` where the second line prints all 4834 files in the target directory including the `dsregcmd` file path. However, after publishing the project as a self-contained application the first line prints `false` where the second line is printing 3027 files out of 4838 in the `system32` path without the `dsregcmd` file path.

I checked the file permissions and all users have read access on the file, also tried to run as administrator but still the same. I'm writing c# since 10 years ago and didn't see something like this before.

Here is how I'm publishing the project:

```
dotnet publish ".\MyProject.csproj" -c Release -r win-x86 --self-contained -o ".\output"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the file cannot be found due to [Windows Filesystem Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for 32-bit apps. You would have to compile your .NET app as x64 in order to see the real system32 directory.

Comment: solved by using Sysynative in case of x86 build instead of System32 to prevent redirections `fileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%windir%\Sysnative\dsregcmd.exe");`

Answer (score 0):

Set property `"Copy to output directory"` with value `"Copy always"` on the file if it's included in the project.